# Validate data in model in VueJS? Any Vue validator doesn't work

Tags: javascript, validation, vue.js

Hello,

as many of you know, you can't use Vue-validator with most of UI components which is making validation difficult.
I am using Vue Material Components by @mjanys which is really nice lib.
Author provided things to handle results of validation - true/false and messages and it is quite common in this kind of libraries,
but HOW CAN I PROVIDE LIVE VALIDATION OF DATA IN MODEL?
I hope I am clear enough but if not, please let me know and I will try to explain more.

I would also need to be able to validate by ajax - e.g. unique user name on registration etc.

Answer (score 1):

So its actually pretty simple but you can tackle it a few ways. The easiest way is to create a validator function that you pass the value and validation type to

I have created a fiddle to illustrate. For validation you can either write your own validation functions or use something like validator.js

https://jsfiddle.net/vbranden/joyeybq8/

in summary the validate function looks like

```
  methods: {
    validate: function (value, type) {
        switch (type) {
        case 'age':
            return value > 0
        case 'alpha':
            return validator.isAlpha(value)
        case 'alphanumeric':
            return validator.isAlphaNumeric(value)
        case 'email':
            return validator.isEmail(value)
        default:
            return true
      }
    }
  }
```

data looks like

```
  data: {
    age: null,
    lastName: '',
    password: '',
    email: ''
  }
```

and in the component

```
<md-input :value.sync="email" type="email" :valid="validate(email, 'email')">
```

you can see that you pass the value to validate which makes it reactive/live and then a type to determine which validation function to run